# IPropertyPage does not show up in tabbed-view

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vsix, vs-extensibility

I am implementing a custom language service for Visual Studio; the project node shall provide some configuration independent property pages (like Application-, Debug-, Build Events, ...) which are displayed in a tabbed view. The registration of property pages works somehow, but they show up in a non-modal dialog, which is not the wanted behavior...

This is what I´ve done...

I´ve a created the `PropertyPageBase` class that implements the `IPropertyPage` interface (I can provide further details of that implementation, if necessary)...

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public abstract class PropertyPageBase : IPropertyPage
{
    private Control control;

    protected abstract Control CreateControl();

    public Control Control
    {
        get { return this.control ?? (this.control = this.CreateControl()); }
    }

    ...
}
```

Custom property pages are derived from that base class; for instance...

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid(...)]
public sealed class GeneralPropertyPage : PropertyPageBase
{
    protected override Control CreateControl()
    {
        return new GeneralPropertyPageControl(this);
    }
}
```

I use `MPF` (Managed Package Framework for Projects) to implement node types for the project hierarchy. So, there´s the `ProjectNodeBase` class (which is derived from MPF `ProjectNode`) where I´ve overriden the `GetConfigurationIndependentPropertyPages` method; this implementation obtains property pages from attached attributes; so I don´t have to override that method again in my concrete implementation...

```
public abstract class ProjectNodeBase : ProjectNode
{
    protected override Guid[] GetConfigurationIndependentPropertyPages()
    {
        Type thisType = this.GetType();

        IEnumerable<Type> pageTypes = thisType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProvideProjectPropertyPageAttribute), true)
            .Cast<ProvideProjectPropertyPageAttribute>()
            .Select(x => x.PropertyPageType);

        return pageTypes.Select(x => x.GUID)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

At my concrete project node class, I just declare project property pages like that...

```
[ProvideProjectPropertyPageAttribute(PropertyPageType = typeof(GeneralPropertyPage))]
public sealed class CustomProjectNode : ProjectNodeBase 
{
    ...
}
```

As I wrote, the property page gets shown when I click the Properties-command within the project´s context menu (in Solution Explorer), but instead of the tabbed view a non-modal dialog appears. So, the question is, how I can tweak it to the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IPropertyPage` implementation shown in the question just works fine...

The reason why the page was not shown in the tabbed property pages frame, was related to the `CustomProjectNode` class (which represents project nodes of my custom project system). I use a modified version of the `Managed Package Framework for Projects` for my project system hierarchy; so `CustomProjectNode` is derived from MPF´s `ProjectNode` class. This class provides the `SupportsProjectDesigner` property, which must be set to `true`.

```
[ProvideProjectPropertyPageAttribute(PropertyPageType = typeof(GeneralPropertyPage))]
public sealed class CustomProjectNode : ProjectNodeBase 
{
    public CustomProjectNode() : base()
    {
        this.SupportsProjectDesigner = true;
    }
}
```